# volatile, Interlocked: trying to break code

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, volatile

First of all, I was trying to find out if using `Interlocked` still requires `volatile` field definition, and that is my real question.

But. Being too lazy to analyse generated MSIL I decided to check it in practice.

I'm trying [MSDN example for `volatile` usage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7.aspx) when code should break in release build with optimizations on. 
And nothing breaks. Code works fine (in this case - main thread terminates gracefully) with optimizations on and off.

1. Do I still require `volatile` keyword on a field when I'm writing to it from one thread using `Interlocked` and reading from another thread without lock?
2. Simple example of code from 1-st question where `volatile` makes difference?
3. Why does MSDN example still working when I remove `volatile` keyword and build in release?

Code snippet to illustrate question 1.

```
class Example
{
    volatile int val;

    void Do()
    {
        Task.Run(() => { while (val == 0) Console.WriteLine("running"); });

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Interlocked.Increment(ref val);
        Console.WriteLine("done.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: God. Don't ever do threading if you try to judge from observation like this. Try running on SMP, a quadcore, try running higher priority, lower. Try random sleeps. Try actively manipulating thread affinitiy. Try a 32bit CLR. Or 64bit. Try using the mono VM. Try running without the debugger. Try actively detecting races, instead hoping to see the ill effects (you know, undefined behaviour is rather hard to disprove. While it might look okay, it would still be undeterministic)

Comment: @sehe Wait, wait, wait. I'm not as stupid as you think. This test was based on information (i have to search a little to find where did i read it) that in this code snippet optimization is being made by *compiler* in 100% cases. 
So it basically caches a variable.

Comment: It's not about whether the optimization is made. You can trust it happens. It is about whether the undefined behaviour is observable

Comment: @sehe under what conditions variable cached for specific thread by compiler can update it's value from the source?

Comment: @Anri: the example you pointed to doesn't use and Interlocked methods.  You might want to post the code you're really asking about so people don't have to guess.

Comment: volatile = memory barrier = removing could work on Intel, fail on other architectures. Intel is very forgiving...

Comment: there is no 'other' architecture anymore. i myself never seen itanium server, i dont know who ever seen itanium, itanium has been retired by intel.. this discussion doesnt make sense - because it has little value, because - those who really understand intrinsics of sharing variables on the level of memory barriers, optimisation, reordering etc - they dont need this confusing DIY research... however **those who doesnt - wont be able to learn from this** anyway.

Comment: @BoppityBop which planet do you live on? Because out here in the real world, there certainly are several different relevant architectures.

Comment: @Boppity Bop, you need to consider ARM and not just Itanium. IIRC, .NET 4.5 no longer supports Itanium but ARM has come into play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the variable is not marked as `volatile`, then code that reads it cannot know that it might be modified by some other thread. So the JIT compiler won't know that keeping the value in a register is potentially unsafe.

`volatile` is how you tell the JIT compiler that other threads can modify the value. That the other thread might use `Interlocked` when changing the value is irrelevant because the JITer might not even know that the other code exists!

It might be that your simple example works because the JIT compiler can see all of the code. Things might be much different if those two bits of code were in separate methods or even different assemblies altogether.

Comment: But they are in separate methods, as far as JIT is concerned.

Comment: @svick: I'm not sure that's entirely true. There could be some information leakage, although I'll admit that if there were, then one would expect that the sample that doesn't use `Interlocked` shouldn't go into an infinite loop, either.

Answer (score 2):

Well, i managed to produce code where `volatile` does make a difference and `Interlocked` does not help. You should run release build without debugger to test it.

```
public class Example
{
    private volatile int val = 0;

    public static void Main()
    {
        var example = new Example();

        Task.Run(() => Interlocked.Increment(ref example.val));

        while (example.val == 0) ;
        // this never happens if val is not volatile
        Console.WriteLine("done.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I'm going to accept @JimMischel's answer as it has some explanations, if nothing more detailed appears.

UPDATE: also found [this blog post](http://igoro.com/archive/volatile-keyword-in-c-memory-model-explained/) explaining some details.

Comment: Running a debug build or attaching a debugger would definitely change the behavior. Likely the original code sample would not go into an infinite loop if running under the Visual Studio debugger.